# Node.JS POST request for input array

Tags: node.js, express

So I want to use for my form, inputs like this: **input name="register[email]"**

But I can not seem to get in router in nodejs the value from input. I used **req.body.register.email** , **reg.body.register['email']**. Nothing seem to work.

When I use for **input name="email"** I can simply use **req.body.email** and works just fine.

Comment: What do you mean `in Java`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access input via `req.body['register[email]']`.

Or, if you use Express, set option `extended` for body-parser.urlencoded in true:

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

and simple use `req.body.register.email`.

Comment: works just fine , thank you. Can you give me some information about extended: true , false ? what influence it will have on my code?

Comment: When true - body-parser uses `qs` library (instead `querystring` module) which allows create nested object from query string. [https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#extended]